# Prolog - How to sort a list of lists containing numbers by the sum of the numbers in each list

Tags: list, sorting, prolog

Assume I have a list that looks like this one:

S1 = [ [3, 6], [1, 3], [4, 12], [10] ]

And I want the sorted list to be:

S = [ [1, 3], [3, 6], [10], [4, 12] ]  ( 4  <  9  <  10   <  16 )

Update:
    I think I come up with a solution using predsort/3 and sumlist/2.

```
mycompare(Comp, [A|C], [B|D]):-
    sumlist(A, X), sumlist(B, Y), 
    (   X < Y -> Comp = '<'
    ;   X > Y -> Comp = '>'
    ;   compare(Comp, [A|C], [B|D])).    

predsort(mycompare, S1, S).
```

Comment: You probably need some kind of program to do that.  If you have trouble writing one, come back to ask for help.

Comment: What do you mean?  I wrote a prolog program and I have a list like that. I need to sort it based on what I asked. I know the predicates like msort/2, sort/2 are not going to work.

Comment: @Alex: Show what you have programmed so far.

Comment: Why do you think that `msort/2` or `sort/2` would not work? A clue: (1) if you have a list `L`, and you form a term `S-L` where `S` is the sum of the elements of list `L`, then it will be true that `S1-L1 @< S2-L2` if `S1 < S2`.

Comment: @lurker: I agree with you.

Comment: You're choosing your comparison operator (`<` or `>`) depending upon the sum, but then calling `compare` on your sublists lists with that operator which attempts to compare lists with a numerical comparator (*e.g.*, `[3,6] < [10]`) which will always fail.

Answer (score 2):

Why use the  slow and non-portable `predsort/3`? 
**Use `keysort/2` instead—it's win-win!**

*Every* ISO-compliant Prolog system provides `keysort/2`—unlike `predsort/3` or `msort/2`...

Using SICStus Prolog 4.3.2 we define `zss_sumsorted/2` like so:

```
:- use_module(library(lists), [maplist/3,sumlist/2,keys_and_values/3]).
:- use_module(library(types), [must_be/4]).

zss_sumsorted(L0, L) :-
   must_be(L0, list(list(integer)), zss_sumsorted(L0,L), 1),
   maplist(sumlist, L0, L1),
   keys_and_values(L10, L1, L0),
   keysort(L10, L10_sorted),
   keys_and_values(L10_sorted, _, L).
```

Sample query as given by the OP:

```
| ?- zss_sumsorted([[3,6],[1,3], [4,12],[10]], Xss).
Xss = [[1,3],[3,6],[10],[4,12]] ? ;
no
```

---

**Edit:**  @tas suggested some more test cases with non-ground instantiation, which should raise the right exceptions—with a little help by `must_be/4`.

```
| ?- zss_sumsorted([[3,6],[1,3],[4,12],[10],[_]], Xss).
! Instantiation error in argument 1 of user:zss_sumsorted/2
! goal:  zss_sumsorted([[3,6],[1,3],[4,12],[10],[_229]],_179)

| ?- zss_sumsorted([[3,6],[1,3],[4,12],[10],x], Xss).
! Type error in argument 1 of user:zss_sumsorted/2
! expected list of an integer, but found x
! goal:  zss_sumsorted([[3,6],[1,3],[4,12],[10],x],_237)
```

Comment: @MatsCarlsson. I'm sure that `| ?- zss_sumsorted([[3,6],[1,3], [4,12],[10],Z], Xss).` **should** raise an instantiation error... But with SICStus Prolog 4.3.2 it does not! Instead, I get one answer `| Z = [],
Xss = [[],[1,3],[3,6],[10],[4,12]] ? ;
no`
What's going on? Please comment.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another version, based on the same idea as suggested by @lurker, but without the elegance of maplist/3:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
:- use_module(library(pairs)).

lists_sorted(L,S) :-
    lists_withsums(L,SL),
    keysort(SL,SSL),             % instead of msort/2
    pairs_values(SSL,S).

lists_withsums([],[]).
lists_withsums([List|Ls], [Sum-List|SLs]) :-
    sum(List,#=,Sum),
    lists_withsums(Ls,SLs).
```

The main difference is the use of keysort/2 instead of msort/2 as the latter also incorporates the actual list in the sorting whereas keysort/2 retains the order in which the lists with equal sums occur. Example query with msort/2:

```
   ?- lists_sorted([[3,6],[3,1],[1,3],[4,12],[10],[2,2],[1,3]], L).
L = [[1,3],[1,3],[2,2],[3,1],[3,6],[10],[4,12]]
```

Same query with keysort/2:

```
   ?- lists_sorted([[3,6],[3,1],[1,3],[4,12],[10],[2,2],[1,3]], L).
L = [[3,1],[1,3],[2,2],[1,3],[3,6],[10],[4,12]]
```

Comment: Beware! Constraints (like `sum/3`) and `keysort/2` don't mix well—only for sufficiently instantiated terms!

Comment: @repeat: True, I was assuming the unsorted list to be variable free. But sumlist/2, at least in YAP, seems to yield similar issues. For the list `[[3,6],[1,3], [4,12],[10],X]` your version produces a result with the assumption `X=[]`, then an instantiation error is raised `X is A+B: expected bound value`. Mine fails straight away with an instantiation error. However for the list `[[3,6],[1,3], [4,12],[10],[3,X]]` my version yields a solution with `[3,X]` at the end and `-3+_A#=X` while yours fails with an instantiation error right away. Do you get similar results for these lists in SICStus?

Comment: Good point! I'll check that out **right now**. Which version of YAP are you using?

Comment: Almost the same (with SICStus), but... With `[[3,6],[1,3], [4,12],[10],X]` I get one answer `X=[]`, but no instantiation error afterwards. With `[[3,6],[1,3], [4,12],[10],[3,X]]` your code behaves exactly as you described.

Comment: YAP 6.2.2 (x86_64-linux). BTW, I tried your version with both sumlist/2 and sum_list/2 with identical results. I also tried the version of @lurker with the two lists above. Same results as your version. Just out of curiosity: Which SICStus version are you using?

Comment: Interesting. FYI: `YAP 6.2.2` (which is the latest stable release, AFAIK) is **very** old! The clpfd-library of it is even older. I have installed a recent "development" version, but it has other issues:(

Comment: Also, `maplist/3` is incomplete with SICStus Prolog 4.3.2. For `| ?- maplist(=,Xs,Ys).` I get **one and only one** answer: `Xs = [],
Ys = [] ? ;
no`... so that needs some fixing, too.

Comment: I'll try and fix my code running on SICStus and edit my answer accordingly (to document its current status).

Answer (score 1):

Several problems with the original code. (1) `A` and `B` are actually the head of *sublists* of your original list, so you really wanted `sumlist` of `[A|C]` and `[B|D]`, not of `A` and `B`. Your disjunction (`;`) logic will mean that `compare/3` is only called if `X = Y` is true. (3) The comparator is being used to compare the lists themselves, which will fail.

```
mycompare(Comp, [A|C], [B|D]):-
    sumlist(A, X), sumlist(B, Y),      % ERROR: A and B are the heads of the list *element*
                                       % you really want sumlist([A|C], X), etc...
    (   X < Y -> Comp = '<'            % Choosing comparator based upon sum
    ;   X > Y -> Comp = '>'            % ERROR: Your disjunction (;) will ONLY do the
                                       % following compare if `X = Y`
    ;   compare(Comp, [A|C], [B|D])).  % ERROR: comparing two lists with comparator
```

---

As another alternative, you can approach the problem this way as hinted in my comments:

1. Map the list to a list of terms `S-L` where `S` is the sum of `L`
2. Use `msort` to sort `S-L` terms which will occur via the "natural" order in Prolog and put smallest `S` first
3. Map the resulting sorted list of `S-L` back to a list of just `L`

The implementation looks like this:

```
sort_by_sum(InputList, SortedList) :-
    maplist(pre_sum, InputList, SumWithList),
    msort(SumWithList, SumWithListSorted),
    maplist(un_sum, SumWithListSorted, SortedList).

pre_sum(L, S-L) :- sumlist(L, S).
un_sum(_-L, L).

?- sort_by_sum([ [3, 6], [1, 3], [4, 12], [10] ], L).
L = [[1, 3], [3, 6], [10], [4, 12]].
```

This works because Prolog will use term comparisons (see `@<`, `@>`, etc in the documentation) in order to do the sort. A term such as `A-B` is less than `X-Y` if `A` is less than `Y`. So comparing `9-[3,6]` with `10-[10]` will find that `9-[3,6]` is less. And comparing `16-[4,12]` with `10-[10]` will find that `16-[4,12]` is greater.

---

As cited in a couple of other answers, `keysort/2` would be more canonical and portable here in place of `msort/2`.

Comment: The way I see things: `predsort/3` + `msort/2` = slowness **plus** *vendor lock-in* :-(

Comment: Consider this query: `?- keysort([1-one,2-two,2-also_two,1-also_one],Xs).` It has one answer: `Xs = [1-one,1-also_one,2-two,2-also_two]`. Bottom line? **`keysort/2` preserves duplicates!**

Comment: @repeat I ran `time/1` on my solution versus other proposed solutions and results were favorable. Thanks for the tip on `keysort`. Interestingly, using the OP's example, my original code shows 49 inferences using `time/1`, but using `keysort` shows 16,027 inferences.

Comment: I get that, but please forgive me if I'm not surprised! I have been that road before in some earlier SO answer... Please run the following query with a recent version of SWI-Prolog and see for yourself! `?- numlist(1,1000000,Zs), time(memberchk(0,Zs)).`

Comment: @repeat are any of the results of `time/1` of any value in trying to determine performance? What about the times shown (which is also less in the case of `msort/2` versus `keysort/2`)?

Comment: Times are better, but it's better to meter different times using `statistics/2`, depending on the concrete benchmark (including or excluding GC time). With memory intensive codes that I measured, SICStus GC is **a lot** faster than SWI's. Apart from that SICStus has a already very impressive JIT (which keeps getting better)!

Answer (score 0):

your solution seems wrong: could be

```
mycompare(C, A, B) :-
    sumlist(A, Sa), sumlist(B, Sb),
    ( Sa < Sb -> C = < ; C = > ).
lol_sorted(L, S) :-
    predsort(mycompare, L, S).
```

or, alternatively:

```
lol_sorted(L, S) :-
    setof(N-E, (member(E,L),sumlist(E,N)), R),
    pairs_values(R, S).
```

this will loose duplicated, identical lists (not sums). To preserve them, a slightly more complex snippet:

```
lol_sorted(L, S) :-
    setof(N/P-E, (nth0(P,L,E),sumlist(E,N)), R),
    pairs_values(R, S).
```

Comment: Could you please point out where my solution has problems? Thanks

Comment: `?- sumlist(1,X).` answers `false`. What I mean, you're passing the first element of the lists, not the lists themselves. And you're going to loose duplicates as well, since compare/3 would return '='